# Put the number of each index in the corresponding place in numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I try to make an array in NumPy and put each index number in the corresponding place in an array 
for example, if my array is a "`ndarray(30,)`" with the size of  30, then :

index 0 = 1

index 1 = 2

.

.

.

index 29 = 30

is there any function in NumPy that do it for me?
if it's not I would appreciate helping me with its code?

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for [numpy.arange](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(start=1, stop=31)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the builtin function `numpy.arange(your_desired_size)` for example :

```
 a = numpy.array([30.3 , 20.5 , 14.2 , 15.3 , 81.2 , 88.4])
 v = numpy.size(a)
 a = np.arange(v)
```